# SPARQL limiting the query result by a variable instead of the number of rows

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, owl, sesame

Lets say I have the following data set:

```
:a  rdf:type      :AClass
:a  :hasName      "a"^^xsd:string
:a  :hasProperty  :xa
:a  :hasProperty  :ya
:a  :hasProperty  :za

:b  rdf:type      :AClass
:b  :hasName      "b"^^xsd:string
:b  :hasProperty  :xb
:b  :hasProperty  :yb

:c  rdf:type      :AClass
:c  :hasName      "c"^^xsd:string
:c  :hasProperty  :xc
```

I want to query the data set to give me back everything of an instance of `:AClass`, but only for two instances. I know I have to use the `LIMIT` keyword, and I have tried a lot of queries but with no success.

In other words, I want to get back this:

```
:a  :hasName      "a"^^xsd:string
:a  :hasProperty  :xa
:a  :hasProperty  :ya
:a  :hasProperty  :za

:b  :hasName      "b"^^xsd:string
:b  :hasProperty  :xb
:b  :hasProperty  :yb
```

How can I limit the result to the number of 2 instances and NOT to number of 2 rows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a subquery to select the two things, and then get the rest of the data in an outer query.  It always helps to show legal working data that we can test with.  The data you've shown isn't actually legal RDF (since it's missing some periods at the ends of lines), but we can easily create a working example.  Here's working data, a query, and the results:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:a a :AClass .
:a :hasName "a" .
:a :hasProperty :xa .
:a :hasProperty :ya .
:a :hasProperty :za .

:b a :AClass .
:b :hasName "b" .
:b :hasProperty :xb .
:b :hasProperty :yb .

:c a :AClass .
:c :hasName "c" .
:c :hasProperty :xc .
```

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?s ?p ?o {
  #-- first, select two instance of :AClass
  { select ?s { ?s a :AClass } limit 2 }

  #-- then, select all the triples of
  #-- which they are subjects
  ?s ?p ?o
}
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| s  | p                                                 | o       |
====================================================================
| :a | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> | :AClass |
| :a | :hasName                                          | "a"     |
| :a | :hasProperty                                      | :xa     |
| :a | :hasProperty                                      | :ya     |
| :a | :hasProperty                                      | :za     |
| :b | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> | :AClass |
| :b | :hasName                                          | "b"     |
| :b | :hasProperty                                      | :xb     |
| :b | :hasProperty                                      | :yb     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I have already tried this solution and it doesn't work. It is limiting the result by row.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in your question, this seems to be what you'd want. This says to select two things that are instances of class a, and then, after those two have been selected, get all the information about them. If you're not getting those results, can you post the exact query you've tried, and the results that you're getting?

Comment: The result is: <someuri> rdf:type cos:Car and <someuri2> rdf:type cos:Car

Comment: @whitefang1993 I've added a complete working example.  The query I've suggested *does* get the results you've requested.  If it doesn't for you, can you let us know what SPARQL engine and version you're using?  Perhaps there's a bug in the implementation.

Comment: I am using Sesame 2.8.4 and I am running the queries from the sesam's Workbench

Comment: I have played around with this problem and I know your answer is correct. I have searched on other forums and I found the same answer. But the only way it works for me is if I put the ?s ?p ?o into a subquery and give it large limit like this {select ?s ?p ?o {?s ?p ?o} limit 100} and than it woks fine... I don't know why and I know this is not best thing to do but I am out of solutions write now.

Comment: If the problem you're actually having is that a query you think should work isn't working on sesame, it would probably be much more helpful (for you) if you post that query along with the data that you're querying. We can say how things should work, but we can't tell you why a query that we haven't actually seen isn't working with data that we haven't seen either.

Comment: I can't post the data set because I am not allowed. But I added to sesame the exact data set that you posted and I ran the exact query that you posted and all I get is two rows:  ( :a rdf:type :AClass ) and ( :a :hasName "a" ). To get your result I have to put the ?s ?p ?o variables into a subquery and give it a limit larger then the number of rows that it should have returned.

Comment: It's sounding more and more like a sesame bug, so your best bet now is probably to ask on their mailing list

Comment: OP added followup question about potential bug in Sesame here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346595/sesame-2-8-4-subquery-limit-bug-fix . Outcome is that it is a bug in the Workbench client's display of the result, not in the query engine itself.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Very interesting;  I'll take a look over there!