# Sesame 2.8.4 subquery limit bug fix?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, sesame

<strike>It seems that there is bug in Sesame 2.8.4.</strike>

If I have the following data set:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>.
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.
@prefix : <http://example.org/>.

:a rdf:type :AClass .
:a :hasName "a"^^xsd:string .
:a :hasProperty :xa .
:a :hasProperty :ya .
:a :hasProperty :za .

:b rdf:type :AClass . 
:b :hasName "b"^^xsd:string .
:b :hasProperty :xb .
:b :hasProperty :yb .

:c rdf:type :AClass .
:c :hasName "c"^^xsd:string .
:c :hasProperty :xc .
```

and run the following query on it:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/> 
select ?s ?p ?o {
#-- first, select two instance of :AClass
{ select ?s { ?s a :AClass } limit 2 }

#-- then, select all the triples of
#-- which they are subjects
?s ?p ?o
}
```

The result I get back is this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| s  | p                                                 | o       |
====================================================================
| :a | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> | :AClass |
| :a | :hasName                                          | "a"     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Instead of this one which is the correct result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| s  | p                                                 | o       |
====================================================================
| :a | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> | :AClass |
| :a | :hasName                                          | "a"     |
| :a | :hasProperty                                      | :xa     |
| :a | :hasProperty                                      | :ya     |
| :a | :hasProperty                                      | :za     |
| :b | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> | :AClass |
| :b | :hasName                                          | "b"     |
| :b | :hasProperty                                      | :xb     |
| :b | :hasProperty                                      | :yb     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone know about this bug? Has anybody encountered the same problem? Or is there another version of Sesame with this bug fixed?

**The next line was added after my question was answered:**

To avoid any confusions: **The bug is in the Workbench and NOT the query engine.
The query engine works perfectly.**

Comment: Not answering your question but you will need `{ select **DISTINCT** ?s { ?s a :AClass } limit 2 }` At the moment, the inner select may return :a and :a.

Comment: @AndyS Sorry but if I add **DISTINCT** it gives me the exact same result. It has no other effect. I already tried it.

Comment: @AndyS: Why should the inner select return twice the same URI? Shouldn't there be only one triple (:a rdf:type :AClass) in the graph?

Comment: Have you checked the [Sesame project support resources](http://rdf4j.org/community.docbook?view) -- bug tracker, mailing list, etc?

Comment: After fixing the problems in your example data and query (missing punctuation and prefix declarations - please post _complete_ examples next time so others can just copy-paste to try and reproduce) I can not reproduce this issue. In both Sesame 2.8.4 or in the later 2.8.6 release I get the correct result. Voting to close.

Comment: That came out grumpier than I intended. If you can still reproduce the issue, can you please share any additional details about how you do this? E.g. what kind of store backend are you using, are you working over HTTP or with a local triplestore, which client tool (console, workbench, etc) are you using? Can you reproduce the issue if you upgrade to release 2.8.6?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I downloaded Sesame 2.8.6 and I deployed the wars (openrdf-sesame.war, openrdf-workbench.war) on wildfly-8.2.0.Final server that is running locally. I added the data set (with the corrections that you made... sorry about that) using workbench. Then I copy pasted the query in the workbench query section and when a ran the query I got back the same two rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309813/sparql-limiting-the-query-result-by-a-variable-instead-of-the-number-of-rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is not a bug in the query engine, but a bug in the Workbench client application (which also explains why I couldn't reproduce it earlier, as I was using the commandline client). For some reason Workbench incorrectly renders the result, showing only 2 rows (despite saying in the header that there are 9 results to be shown):

[image]

The problem is related to the result paging functionality in the Workbench, because when you change that setting it suddenly does show the complete result:

[image]

This issue has now been logged as a bug in Sesame's issue tracker: [SES-2307](https://openrdf.atlassian.net/browse/SES-2307).